# Xcopy change source folder if doesn't exist

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, directory, xcopy

I don't have any problem to do Xcopy, but the source folder may be not the one specified. It could be one among three folders.

So I would like a proceed that

```
set sourcefolder = "folder1"
if not exist set sourcefolder = "folder2"
if not exist set sourcefolder = "folder3"
if not exist exit
```

But I'm a newbie in scripting, so I would be glad if anyone could help me please.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code:

- do *not* put spaces around the `=` in a `set` command line, because `set sourcefolder = path` assigns <kbd>SPACE</kbd>`path` to the variable `sourcefolder`<kbd>SPACE</kbd>;
- use the `set` syntax `set "sourcefolder=C\MyFolder"`; the quotes `""` do *not* become part of the variable value here, so place them when *expanding* (reading) the variable like `"%sourcefolder%"`;
- after `if not exist` you need to specify *what* to check, like `if not exist "%sourcefolder%"`;
- to end a batch file use `exit /B` rather than `exit` as the latter terminates also the command prompt (`cmd`) instance;

Here is the fixed code:

```
set "sourcefolder=C:\MyFolder"
if not exist "%sourcefolder%" set "sourcefolder=D:\MyFolder"
if not exist "%sourcefolder%" set "sourcefolder=E:\MyFolder"
if not exist "%sourcefolder%" (
    echo Could not find a valid source folder.
    exit /B
)
xcopy /E /I /Y "%sourcefolder%" "V:\Save\"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot aschipfl for the solution and the tips!!

Comment: You're welcome! so if my answer helped you, consider to upvote and/or accept it... thanks!